# Output HTML Tree With Array

Tags: php, html, arrays, tree

Is there a more elegant way to output the given html structure with an array? I found some recursive solutions but therefore a parent_id is needed (if I understand correctly).

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Level 1</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Level 2</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>Level 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Array**

```
Array
(
[0] => Level 1
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Level 2
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Level 3
            )

    )

)
```

**Loops**

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($array as $arr) : ?>
    <li>
    <?php if(is_array($arr)) : ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($arr as $a) : ?>
                <li>
                <?php if(is_array($a)) : ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($a as $aa) : ?>
                            <li><?php echo $aa; ?></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php echo $a; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php echo $arr; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I´m a bit worried about the performance of this approach :-D

Comment: Why don't use echo for the HTML tags as well?

Comment: why don't you check performance yourself?

Comment: I think readability is a bigger concern than performance there. It looks like one of those optical illusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it just recursive:

```
<?PHP

function doOutputList($TreeArray)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($TreeArray as $arr)
    {
        echo '<li>';
        if(is_array($arr)) 
        {
                doOutputList($arr);
        }
        else
        {
                echo $arr;
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

doOutputList($array);

?>
```

Or if you like good readable HTML Code try this:

```
<?PHP

function doOutputList($TreeArray, $deep=0)
{
    $padding = str_repeat('  ', $deep*3);

    echo $padding . "<ul>\n";
    foreach($TreeArray as $arr)
    {
        echo $padding . "  <li>\n";
        if(is_array($arr)) 
        {
                doOutputList($arr, $deep+1);
        }
        else
        {
                echo $padding .'    '. $arr;
        }
        echo $padding . "  </li>\n";
    }
    echo $padding . "</ul>\n";
}

doOutputList($array);

?>
```